# Proving $(b^m)^\frac{1}{n} = (b^p)^\frac{1}{q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

This is from Rudin Exercise 1.6(a).

It asks to prove that if $m, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n,q \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}$ then for all 0 < b $\in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $(b^m)^\frac{1}{n} = (b^p)^\frac{1}{q}$

I know we can show that any $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ exists and is unique from a previous proof by Rudin, but I'm completely stuck. Any form of help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose 
\begin{align}
\frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ mq = np
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
b^{mq}= b^{np}
\end{align}
because $mq$ and $np$ are integers. Next, by existence/uniqueness of radicals, we have
\begin{align}
 (b^m)^q =b^{mq} = b^{np}  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b^m = (b^{np})^{1/q} = (\underbrace{b^p \cdots b^p}_{n-\text{times}})^{1/q} = \underbrace{(b^p)^{1/q}\dots (b^p)^{1/q}}_{n-\text{times}} = [(b^p)^{1/q}]^n.
\end{align}
Thus, again by the existence/uniqueness of radicals, we have that
\begin{align}
(b^{m})^{1/n} = (b^p)^{1/q}.
\end{align}

Comment: OH. This is such a wonderful explanation. Thank you so, so, so much!